# Find If Value Exists on other Worksheet (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a macro tied to a button click event on my Excel worksheet. When this event fires, I need to see if the value on my worksheet `FeedSampleForm` `Range("A5:B5").Value` exists anywhere in column `B` of my other worksheet `FeedSamples`.

Can anyone assist me with this? I'm barely a user when it comes to Excel, and this is my first time "Developing" with it.

**EDIT**:

Current Code below. This is for different save procedures depending on if saving a new record or saving after editing a previously created record.

For Sample Data, say I'm looking for "FeedSampleForm".Range("A5:B5").Value which is "SR0238", I need to see if "SR0238" exists in column B on "FeedSamples" worksheet, currently containing "SR0237" - "SR0252". If it doesn't exist, I can use same code as my Add Record functionality, but if it does, I have to write to that exact row when saving.

```
Sub SaveInspection()
    If modeAdd = True Then
    'Labeler Reg. No.
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("L3:M3").value
    'Feed Report No.
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("A5:B5").value
    'Product No. / Class No.
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("C5").value
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("D5").value
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("E5").value
    'Description No.
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("H5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("F5").value
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("I5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("G5").value
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("J5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("H5").value
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("K5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("I5").value
    'Possessor No.
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("L1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("J5:K5").value
    'Date
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("M").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("L5:M5").value
    'Possessor Name
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AB1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("A8:F8").value
    'Possessor Address
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AC1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("A10:F10").value
    'Possessor City/St
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AD1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("A11:E11").value
    'POssessor Zipcode
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AE1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("F11").value
    'Labeler Name
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AF1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("H8:M8").value
    'Labeler Address
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AG1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("H10:M10").value
    'Labeler City/St
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AH1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("H11:L11").value
    'Labeler Zipcode
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AI1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("M11").value
    'Product Name
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AJ1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("A13:I13").value
    '1. Med
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AK1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("J13:K13").value
    '2. Non-Med
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AL1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("L13:M13").value
'No. Bags/Loc. Sampled

    'Total No. Guarantees
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("P").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("C15:E15").value
    'Flag Sample
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("Q").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("F15:G15").value
    'Sample Def.
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("R").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("H15:I15").value
    'Compliance

    'Duplicate

    'Bag Tag Mark or Code
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("U").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("A17:H17").value
    'On Hand
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("V").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("I17:K17").value
    'Approx. Wt/Lbs
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("W").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("L17:M17").value
    'Remarks
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("AA").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("A19:M19").value
    'Sample Taken From

    'Sample Method

    'Form

    'Probe Size

    'Product No./Class No.
    Worksheets("FeedSamples").Range("D").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).value = Range("A23:C23").value

    modeAdd = False
End If

If modeEdit = True Then
    'find the record in "datatable" and save over fields.
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FeedSamples")

    'Range("O3").Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Range("A5:B5").Value, sheet.Range("B:B"), 0)), "Not Found", "Value found on row " & MATCH(Range("A5:B5").Value, sheet.Range("B:B"), 0))"
    'Range("O3").Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(12345,A:A,0)),"Not Found","Value found on row " & MATCH(12345,A:A,0)))"

    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A5:B5").value, sheet.Range("B2:B25000"), 2, False)
    'Throws Object Required Error
    MsgBox result
    modeEdit = False
    allowNav = True

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your existing code?

Comment: Are you searching for multiple values? "A5:B5" or is that one value split up? Can you provide any sample data.

Comment: Edited to add code and sample data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very easy way is to declare the range that you want to search in and the value that you want to find.

```
Sub findValue()

    Dim xlRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim valueToFind

    valueToFind = "MyValue"
    Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("B1:B10")

    For Each xlCell In xlRange
        If xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then
            'Do Something
        End If
    Next xlCell

End Sub
```

I'm assuming that your range of ("A5:B5") is a merged cell because you indicated that it contained a single value. Merged cells can just be referenced by the "top left" cell within the merge (or at least that's how I think of it). So your merged range of ("A5:B5") can be referred to as just ("A5"). Anyway, here is a modified version of the method above that is more suited for your needs.

```
Sub findValue(ByVal valueToFind As String)

    Dim xlRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim xlFormSheet As Worksheet
    Dim xlSamplesSheet As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Integer
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    bFound = False
    Set xlFormSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FeedSampleForm")
    Set xlSamplesSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FeedSamples")

    iLastRow = xlSamplesSheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row

    Set xlRange = xlsamplesheet.Range("B1:B" & iLastRow)

    For Each xlCell In xlRange
        If xlCell.value = valueToFind Then
            bFound = True '<-- The value was found
            iRow = xlCell.Row '<-- Here is the row that the value was found on
        End If

        If bFound Then Exit For '<-- Optional: Exit the for loop once the value is found the first time
    Next xlCell

End Sub
```

Comment: You've got me in the right direction, but it's not fully functional yet. When using the below code, I get a type mistmatch error for Set valueToFind = xlFormSheet.Range("A5:B5").value.

Comment: '    Dim xlRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim xlFormSheet As Worksheet
    Dim xlSamplesSheet As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Integer
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim valueToFind
    
    

    bFound = False
    Set xlFormSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FeedSampleForm")
    Set xlSamplesSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FeedSamples")
    Set valueToFind = xlFormSheet.Range("A5:B5").value

    iLastRow = xlSamplesSheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown).row

    Set xlRange = xlSamplesSheet.Range("B1:B" & iLastRow)

    For Each xlCell In xlRange

Comment: In the example I used above, I declared valueToFind as a string (based on the example data you provided). So don't use 'Set valueToFind'.   Instead simply use 'valueToFind = xlFormSheet.Range("A5").value'

Comment: Thanks! Just to solve the headache I went ahead and took out the variable just using the actual cell range I'm looking for. Looks like most of it is working now! I did a recent post having issues with Excel auto-converting my contents if you feel like taking a crack at it. One field value of "22/50" ends up as 0.44.

Comment: This worked from me when removed the Set for the iLastRow